# getAssets().open - open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android

I'm trying to copy a file from the assets folder to the app's data directory/internal storage.

The file is saved in the assets folder with the filename `eng.traineddata`.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "eng.traineddata");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("eng.traineddata");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("eng.traineddata");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
            int length = inputStream.read(buffer);
            while (length > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                length = inputStream.read(buffer);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("APP_INITIALIZER", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But I always get this message in the logcat: `eng.traineddata: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)`

Comment: The "new File()" on first line is likely the cause of the problem, not the open() on the fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `OutputStream` like this:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(getPackageName();, 0);
    String dataDir = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;

    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dataDir +"/eng.traineddata");
```